# how to copy multiple selections from excel to word (manually and/or VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Using Excel/Word 2007 I'm trying to copy multiple selections from Excel to Word. When I paste it into Word it's as if it ignored the break in the ranges and just pastes a range that includes everything I was trying to leave out.

For instance if I intend to copy/paste `"A2:D4, A6:D7, A10:D11"` what is actually pasted in word is `"A2:D11"`, so it's ignoring the breaks in the selections. I can't seem to find any documentation on this issue anywhere. If someone knows anything I'd really appreciated it. I know I'm selecting the ranges properly because if I copy and paste the multiple ranges within Excel it works like it should.

The actual issue is that I have these actions automated in a macro and I'd really prefer not to loop through the individual ranges because they're stored in a dictionary and it would be just a real hassle. Despite that, it seems weird that I can't even accomplish the task manually.

I've done quite a bit of digging and can't seem to come up with anything. I thought about using the Office clipboard but you can't paste tables as an RTF. It doesn't seem like there are any options when pasting with the office clipboard.

AFAIK it doesn't seem possible and I've tried to exhaust all my normal avenues of knowledge before posting here. If anyone has ever just experienced this it would be comforting to know I'm not alone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent that from happening, but you could potentially work around it by pasting your non-continuous selection into a continuous region in a new, temporary sheet/workbook, then copying the continuous region from the temp sheet/workbook into word.

a bit of a hassle, yes, but it should get the job done.